# Reading data from a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. When the second is activated I need to read the first and insert info into  the second.
The code below should do this but it is reading the second sheet,"Cabinet install", instead of the first. What is wrong?

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Sumknobs As Integer
Dim Cabsht As Worksheet
Dim Installsht As Worksheet

Set Cabsht = Worksheets("Cabinets")
Set Installsht = Worksheets("Cabinet Install")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Cabsht.Activate

With Worksheets("Cabinets")
    For j = 1 To 4
    For k = 1 To 46
        Sumknobs = Sumknobs + .Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 2) * Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 1)
    Next k
    Next j
    For j = 1 To 2
    For k = 1 To 71
        Sumknobs = Sumknobs + .Cells(k + 4, 5 * j + 18) * Cells(k + 4, 5 * j + 19)
    Next k
    Next j
End With

Installsht.Cells(17, 6) = Sumknobs
```

Comment: This code works on my excel. No matter which one is the initial active sheet, after execution, the excel window stays at sheet 'Cabinets', and result is in cell F7 of sheet 'Cabinet install'. My env: Microsoft Office Home and student 2019, Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some ***.*** 's

Replace:

```
Sumknobs = Sumknobs + .Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 2) * Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 1)
```

with:

```
Sumknobs = Sumknobs + .Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 2) * .Cells(k + 4, 5 * j - 1)
```

same for the second loop-set.

Comment: But without the dot, it is still referencing to the `ActiveSheet`, which is `Worksheets("Cabinets")`.